# layout_weight attribute in <include> tag

Tags: android

I'm trying to reuse some layout components in android application using `<include>` tag. I've got different port and land layouts:

1. Port:

   ```
   <LinearLayout a:layout_weight="1" a:layout_width="match_parent" a:layout_height="0dp">

       <include layout="@layout/calc_equals_button" a:layout_weight="4"/>
       <include layout="@layout/calc_display"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Land:

   ```
   <LinearLayout a:layout_weight="1" a:layout_width="match_parent" a:layout_height="0dp">

       <include layout="@layout/calc_equals_button"/>
       <include layout="@layout/calc_display"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Main difference is **`a:layout_weight="4"`**, so i want my calc_equals_button component to be smaller in port orientation.

The thing is if i try to embed `calc_equals_button` component directly everything works OK, e.g.:

```
<LinearLayout a:layout_weight="1" a:layout_width="match_parent" a:layout_height="0dp">
        <DirectionDragButton
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                a:id="@+id/equalsButton"
                a:text="="
                a:layout_width="match_parent"
                a:layout_height="match_parent"
                a:layout_weight="4"
                style="@style/control_button_style"
                a:onClick="numericButtonClickHandler"/>

        <include layout="@layout/calc_display"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

otherwise - NOT.

Here is sample of calc_equals_button.xml:

```
<DirectionDragButton
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:id="@+id/equalsButton"
    a:text="="
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/control_button_style"
    a:onClick="numericButtonClickHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A current limitation of  is that you *must* specify layout_width and layout_height for other layout_* attributes to be applied.

Comment: "Current" as in it will be changed in ICS?

Comment: But how this can help to the issue?

Comment: @MichellBak No, this limitation is still present in ICS.

Comment: @se.solovyev It solves your problem... Your include tag must specify a width and a heigh for the weight to be taken into account.